# Why there are some the laws of phyiscs written for specific case?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, acceleration, laws-of-physics

I am a new physics self student. I noticed that the laws of phyiscs are written for specific case, for example Newton's second law (in Wikipedia page https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion): For a particle of mass $m$, the net force $F$ on the particle is equal to the mass $m$ times the particle's acceleration $a$:
$$
F=ma.
$$
The law is talking about specific particle, not only Newton's second law but also Newton's law of gravitation. I know the law applies to every object in the universe but why is written for a specific particle? Not only newton second law and newton law of gravation all physics laws i have seen are written for specific case.including Coulomb's law <<The magnitude of the electrostatic force $F$ between two point charges q1 and q2 is directly proportional to the product of the magnitudes of charges and inversely proportional to the square of the distance between them. Like charges repel each other, and opposite charges mutually attract>>. it is written for specific point charge or at least this is what i understood. why not to write the laws in general .or they are not written for a specific case and i have miss understand this ?

Comment: It can be argued that Newton's 2nd Law is a special case of the law of conservation of momentum.

Comment: This question is currently closed so I can't post an answer. I believe the answer is that all laws of physics are for "specific" cases... in fact, these cases are abstract idealizations that only approximate the actual behavior of the real-world systems (though very accurately in many cases). Some idealizations in these laws are particles having zero size or being under the influence of only one force at a time. Other approximations include neglecting known corrections, such as Newton's laws neglecting quantum and relativistic effects. "All models are wrong, some are useful."

Comment: In the example you give, $m$ and $a$ can be **any** value, so it's not limited to a specific case. The same goes for most  equations in physics.

Comment: Because from experience we know that a bigger system can be viewed as the sum of its parts (careful here). You find the law of an individual **point-like** object and them after careful observation define or create a specific rule for summing up $n$ of those points as smaller parts of a bigger object. One cool aspect of this is the fact that the summing rule is in many cases just the usual algebraic sum, which can be easily generalized into an infinite sum of point-like objects by integration.

Comment: @J.Manuel ..what i mean in my question is that for example newton second law is written for one particle ..of mass m and acceleration a ... Not it is written for special case ..the law is talking about one particle not particles in general

Comment: @HomamHassn Newton law *is written for any particle* which as being stripped out of any other property (including size) but mass. If I say the roots of the algebraic equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ are $x=\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}$, I’m not talking about any *specific* roots $x$. I’m talking about all possible $x$’s that solve $ax^2+bx+c=0$. In physics when they say *a particle* they mean any possible object that has no size, but the properties mass $m$ and charge $q$.

Answer (score 1):

It is written for a specific particle sometimes, but that's just a matter of language. Generally in physics if they write the law in singular ("a particle" rather than "any particle"), they mean that it applies to any particle. If they are talking about a specific particle or type of particle, it will be clear from the context which particle(s) are meant.